# Finding Layouts that Don't Exist

Tags: java, android, view, listactivity

How do i call setContentView() on the following activity?

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        String[] values = new String[] { 
            "Android", 
            "iPhone", 
            "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", 
            "WebOS", 
            "Ubuntu", 
            "Windows7", 
            "Max OS X",
            "Linux", 
            "OS/2" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

As you can see, ListActivities don't necessarily require a layout file; but i've gotten used to having one (grin). I have a MenuDrawer that needs to run setContentView()...i'm open to any options.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called the Activity's getListView():

```
mMenuDrawer.setContentView(getListView());
```

Why do i always figure things out AFTER i post to StackOverflow???

Answer (score 1):

You call `setContentView()` like you would with any other Activity, though ListActivities have one extra requirement: the layout must have a ListView with this attribute: `android:id="@android:id/list"`.

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_myListActivity);
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the sample posted by MenuDrawer here [ListActivitySample](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer/blob/master/samples/src/net/simonvt/menudrawer/samples/ListActivitySample.java). It seems the key is overriding the `setContentView` that is called on your behalf by ListActivity and forwarding it into your menu drawer.

The following seems to be the key:

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    // This override is only needed when using MENU_DRAG_CONTENT.
    mMenuDrawer.setContentView(layoutResID);
    onContentChanged();
}
```